# Dart menu and sub menu link to new pages

Tags: dart

I'm really new to coding, I'm trying to make an app with multiple pages and I'm stuck. My menu has NHL and the sub menus will have different sports teams to select under them, I've created the menu but when I try to click the sub menu in the UI I get an error in console. Here's my code, thank you for any assistance:
[text](https://gist.github.com/flnEGknEF/d93809e8adc11320667dfda1f4d1f347)

Answer (score 0):

Please paste error as well. So you may reach your answer quicker.